# how can i fetch next week day (like if i inserted input as "Saturday" then output has to be next Saturday with date) using python 2.7.13?

Tags: python, python-2.7

if i inserted input as "Saturday" then output should be coming Saturday of week like if today is Friday then output should be tomorrow date or else output should be date of next Saturday.how can i solve this problem using python 2.7.13 ?

Comment: what have you tried so  far? what is not working for you ?

Comment: See [**`calendar`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [python-dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil), according to their documentation you can do:

```
>>> TODAY+relativedelta(weekday=calendar.FRIDAY)
datetime.date(2003, 9, 19)
```